# smack Message not comming when my message Type is Message.Type.groupchat

Tags: xmpp, smack

I am sending a message to jabber as

```
Message msgMultipleChat = new Message(to);//,Message.Type.chat);

msgMultipleChat.setBody(inputChatText);
msgMultipleChat.setType(Message.Type.groupchat);
msgMultipleChat.setFileType("text");
msgMultipleChat.setFile("");
//msgMultipleChat.setFriendName(userIds);
msgMultipleChat.setFrom(userIds);
msgMultipleChat.setGroupId(mGroupId);
if(BizproConnection.mXMPPConnection.getHost()!=null ) {
    BizproConnection.mXMPPConnection.sendPacket(msgMultipleChat);
}
```

I am not able to recieve it but when the Message type is chat i am able to recieve it why is it so

Comment: ofcourse to is not JID ie roomAddress i acknowledge this but the message is going from android to iphone but not from android to android may be its going and am not able to recieve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the value of `to` is *not* the JID of a MUC then the message is invalid because `Type.Groupchat` is only valid when communicating with a MUC instance ([XEP-0045](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html)).